# How to resolve 'syntax error, unexpected MROWCLOSE, expecting ROWSEP or ENDENV at token }' while trying equations cross-referencing in asciidoctor-pdf

Tags: cross-referencing, pdf

Trying to use cross-referencing of latex-equations in 'asciidoctor-pdf' as below...

```
Pressure drop equation (\ref{eqn_PressureDrop}).

[latexmath]
++++
\begin{equation}\label{eqn_PressureDrop}
\Delta P=f\left(\frac{
{L}}
{{D_{h}}
}\right)\frac{
{\rho u^{2}}}
{{2}
}
\end{equation}
++++
```

pdf file shows 'ref{eqn_PressureDrop}' instead of the reference to the equation. Also, getting below error 'syntax error, unexpected MROWCLOSE, expecting ROWSEP or ENDENV at token }' as output.

Any suggestions/guidance please, how to correct the equation cross-referencing here?

I modified my above script a bit like below:

```
[latexmath#eqnone,reftext=eqnone]
++++
\begin{equation}\tag{eqnone}
\Delta P=f\left(\frac{
{L}}
{{D_{h}}
}\right)\frac{
{\rho u^{2}}}
{{2}
}
\end{equation}
++++

Pressure drop equation <<eqnone>>.
```

And can see the below result.
[image]

Static referencing ('eqnone') is happening here but would like to cross-refer the dynamic generated equation number here.
So, Can we do anything to refer the automatic generated equation number ('9' here)?

Comment: The code is fine, apart from some unnecessary braces, but is this really related to LaTeX?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies for not making the question clear. Have tried to edit my question, please let me know if that's okay now.

Comment: @WpfBee: Try dropping the `_` in the `\label` and `\ref`. Just a guess.

Comment: It seems asciidoctor with html output may sort of support this (using MathJax), but asciidoctor-pdf using asciidoctor-mathematical does not support it currently (and the architecture is not very suitable to implement it). See https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-mathematical/issues/37 for some discussion. Also the alternative using Mathoid mentioned on https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/#stem-support probably would not help as it seems to convert equations directly to images without preserving the Javascript that would allow for crossreferencing.

Comment: Updated my question a bit with some latest updates, kindly see if dynamic cross-referencing can be possible here @Werner. Thanks in advance!!